# Find the value of ${x^2} - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor - 2 = 0$

Tags: functions

Find the value of ${x^2} - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  - 2 = 0$.

Based on the graph we have three values of x viz. $x={-1,\sqrt3,2}$

How do I proceed

N is not a natural number but an Integer either positive or negative or zero in both case

CASE $1$:

$x \in N$, hence $ \Rightarrow {N^2} - N - 2 = 0 \Rightarrow {N^2} - 2N + N - 2 = 0 \Rightarrow N\left( {N - 2} \right) + \left( {N - 2} \right) = 0,N \in \left\{ { - 1,2} \right\}$

CASE $2$:
$x = N + a,a \in \left( {0,1} \right)$,

${\left( {N + a} \right)^2} - N - 2 = 0 \Rightarrow {N^2} + 2aN + {a^2} - N - 2 = 0 \Rightarrow {N^2} + 2N\left( {a - \frac{1}{2}} \right) + {a^2} - 2 = 0 \Rightarrow {N^2} + 2N\left( {a - \frac{1}{2}} \right) + {a^2} - a + \frac{1}{4} = 2 + \frac{1}{4} - a$

$ \Rightarrow {\left( {N - \left( {a - \frac{1}{2}} \right)} \right)^2} = \frac{9}{4} - a \Rightarrow N = \left( {a - \frac{1}{2}} \right) \pm \sqrt {\frac{9}{4} - a} $

How do I select a cvalue such that N is an integer and $a\in(0,1) $

Comment: [SyberMaths](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCW4czokv40JYR-w7u6aXZ3g) solved it yesterday: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVvZghjvxo0

Comment: Your second to last step contains an error. It should be $$\biggl[N \color{blue}{+} \biggl(a - \frac{1}{2}\biggr)\biggr]^2 = \frac{9}{4} - a.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observe that any integer solutions to $x^2-x-2=0$ will also solve $x^2-\lfloor{x}\rfloor-2=0$. Thus $\{-1,2\}$.

To find noninteger roots for $x$ render $x>\lfloor{x}\rfloor>x-1$ from which $x^2-x-2<0<x^2-x-1$, forcing a noninteger root to lie in $(-1,(1-\sqrt5)/2)$ or $((1+\sqrt5)/2,2)$ and therefore $\lfloor{x}\rfloor\in\{-1,1\}$. Substitute each candidate value for $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ into the original equation and check for noninteger roots with the assumed value of $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$. This gives $\lfloor{x}\rfloor=1,x=\sqrt3$.

Comment: Is the first line meant to say $x^2 - x - \color{blue}{2} = 0$?

Comment: Typos suck. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it the other way around : you need $N\in\mathbb Z$ and $a\in[0,1)$ such that :
$$(N+a)^2 =  N+2$$
so $N\geq -2$ and :
$$a = -N\pm\sqrt{N+2}\in [0,1)$$

For the $+$ sign, a quick study of the function $f(x) = -x+\sqrt{x+2}$ shows that the only integers with $f(n) \in [0,1)$ are $N= 1$, which gives $x=N+a = \sqrt{3}$, and $N = 2$, which gives $ x=N+a= 2$.

For the $-$ sign, looking at $g(x) = -x-\sqrt{x+2}$, we see that the only solution is $N=-1$, which gives $x=N+a=-1$

Answer (score 4):

If you write $x=N+a$, where $N=\lfloor x\rfloor$ is integer and $a=x-N\in[0,1)$, you can divide into three cases.

If $N>0$, we have $N\le N+a<N+1$ and so
$$
N^2-N-2\le N^2+2aN+a^2-N-2<N^2+2N+1-N-2
$$
and so we need $N^2-N-2\le0$ and $N^2+N-1>0$ (this is just a necessary condition, though) which forces $N=1$ or $N=2$ (check it).

If $N=1$, the equation becomes $a^2+2a-2=0$, so $a=\sqrt{3}-1$ and this yields $x=\sqrt{3}$.

If $N=2$, the equation becomes $a^2+4a=0$, so $a=0$ and this yields $x=2$.

If $N=0$ the equation is $a^2-2=0$, which has no solution in the interval $[0,1)$.

If $N<0$, the above inequalities reverse, so we need
$$
N^2+N-1<0,\qquad N^2-N-2\ge0
$$
that only allows $N=-1$. In this case the equation becomes
$$
a^2-2a=0
$$
and so $a=0$. So we find the third solution $x=-1$.